# Creating an SQL view that returns person details, caregivers and team plays in

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I am wanting to create a view using MYSQL that lists all players in that play in a team, their guardians (note: a player can have a single parent or both) the guardians phone number and the team the player plays in. I'm not quite sure how to do this but I know there are many joins involved. The following image shows all tables in my database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select Team.tName, PlayerPerson.Name,GuardianPerson.Phone
From Player
Join Person as PlayerPerson On Player.PersonId = PlayerPerson.PersonID
Join PlayerTeam on Player.PersonId = PlayerTeam.PersonId
Join Team on PlayerTeam.TeamId = Team.TeamId
Join Guardian on Player.PersonId = Child.Id
Join Person as GuardianPerson on Guardian.ParentID = GuardianPerson.PersonID
```

I think